# change window focus to InstallShield Wizard ran from .msi

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, installshield, sendkeys

I am trying to install a .msi file through PowerShell script with sendkeys to send keystrokes to the InstallShield Wizard once it launches. The msi is a bit wonky and won't take parameters required for installation through PS. Also tried Orca to no avail.
**The main problem is Windows doesn't focus on the msi InstallShield Wizard when it pops up**. Once I click on it then the input from sendkeys works fine. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "****.msi" 
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('System Dashboard-***** - InstallShield Wizard')
Sleep 20
$wshell.SendKeys('{ENTER}')
Sleep 2
$wshell.SendKeys("adadasds")
Sleep 2
$wshell.SendKeys("asdasd")
Sleep 2
$wshell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
```

Comment: Are you trying to install in GUI mode using msi file?

Comment: yes, as the MSI won't take in parameters through Powershell.

Comment: You can pass parameters to msi through -ArgumentList in powershell

Comment: This MSI requires you put the url/port during the installation and I know the name of the property from the msi log file. You cannot pass that property value through powershell with -ArgumentList. You can see the property name in the log but not in Orca Property Table.

Comment: Is the property names in all caps? if yes, I guess you can pass it. Or I would suggest to pass those property from command-line using CMD(just to test) and launch GUI of msi installer. If this works, Url/port field should be auto populated. Otherwise, look for Control table in orca and try to find the field you're looking for. If found, look for the property column if any property is bind to it.

Comment: Yes its in caps but can't pass it. Theres also no Control table. Got ISXmlEllementAttrib, ISXmlElement, ISXmlFile. The Property is feeding value to one of the XmlElement and I tried editing that but with no success, Thanks.

Comment: can you share msi log while passing property from command-line using cmd?

Comment: No. I have resorted to ahk to do the gui window switch.